# Excel - Keep macros enabled when sheet is saved as new

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel macro-enabled sheet that users open, fill out a list of information (name, date, etc) and click a save button. This creates a new file name based on the information, and saves the file to a network location. The users then continue to work with the sheet.

I forced the users to enable macros (excellent tutorial here: http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/forcing-your-clients-to-enable-macros/) and that works well, however once the file name changes, macros are disabled. I assume this due to the fact that it is an untrusted network location. The sheet will be used by many different computers, so I would like to find a vba workaround rather than relying on an excel setting.

Edit: I think I have the answer: As @mehow said based on the link I have posted, I can first run the part of the macro that finds the file name, then lock the workbook all except the start page, then save the workbook as the new name, then hide the start page and show everything else. That way if macros are disabled once the sheet is saved it should force the user to re-enable without compromising the protection. I'll post once I find outwhether it will work.

Edit: It works! Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK there is no VBA workaround for this. And there shouldn't be per se for security reasons :)

Comment: Understand @SiddharthRout, what I want to do is tell the user that they must enable macros again before they are allowed to continue.

Comment: If the macros are disabled then how can there be a VBA workaround?

Comment: You can sign the macro with a personal digital certificate and ask user to import that cert to "Trusted Publishers" and "Trusted Root Certificates", and ensure Macro Settings is "Disabl all macros except digitally signed macros" is selected. This becomes path independent. Use GPO to automate if it's domained computer.

Comment: @user2967539 hide all sheets except one that says "please enable macros to use this workboook".

Comment: on top of what mehow said, make that very hidden so the user can't manually unhide it. I think that's what's discussed in the tutorial you posted? what other problems do you encounter? if it's what Siddart is pointing out `VBA disabled` then there is no workaround. When you say `VBA is disabled` does it mean that it is disabled in the user's system?

Comment: I am wondering about two things:

1. Is problem caused by saving your spreadsheet and then you have no chance to enable macros?

2. Do you want macros to be enabled right after opening spreadsheet? 

Second thing is impossible unless someone turned off security options. When comes to first - check file extension. Remember that macros are handled only by XLS and XLSM extensions, XLSX is macros disabled extension.

Comment: @lowak .xlsb will also save and allow macros to run. It's also, allegedly, more compact and faster to load/save than .xlsx or .xlsm.

Comment: @SiddharthRout but there is a `vbs` workaround :)